# RestEasy + hibernate + JBoss EAP 5.1.1

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, resteasy

I am developing a webservice using RestEasy API 2.3.0 GA, hibernate 3.6.3, mysql and trying to deploy on Jboss 5.1.1.

It is a maven project and getting deployed successfully.
But when I call my webservice from a client I am getting exceptions.
My maven dependencies are:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.GA</version>
        <!-- filter out unwanted jars -->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jettison-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.GA</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.xml.stream</groupId>
                <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Relevant parts of exceptions are as follows:

```
  9:14:41,813 ERROR [STDERR] Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.AnnotationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator.<init>(java.lang.Class, java.util.ResourceBundle, org.hibernate.validator.MessageInterpolator, java.util.Map, org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager)
19:14:41,818 ERROR [Application]] Servlet.service() for servlet javax.ws.rs.core.Application threw exception
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleApplicationException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:340)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:214)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:190)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:540)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:502)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:183)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:95)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:599)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:451)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at uk.co.dcm.utils.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:38)
    at uk.co.dcm.utils.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:27)
    at uk.co.dcm.olympics.adult.AdultDAO.addAdult(AdultDAO.java:13)
    at uk.co.dcm.olympics.adult.AdultService.addAdult(AdultService.java:8)
    at uk.co.dcm.olympics.adult.AdultRest.post(AdultRest.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:154)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:525)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator.<init>(java.lang.Class, java.util.ResourceBundle, org.hibernate.validator.MessageInterpolator, java.util.Map, org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyHibernateValidatorLegacyConstraintsOnDDL(Configuration.java:1654)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyConstraintsToDDL(Configuration.java:1626)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1418)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1829)
    at uk.co.dcm.utils.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:33)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator.<init>(java.lang.Class, java.util.ResourceBundle, org.hibernate.validator.MessageInterpolator, java.util.Map, org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyHibernateValidatorLegacyConstraintsOnDDL(Configuration.java:1642)
    ... 43 more
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: How are you obtaining your dependencies? If you're not using Maven or similar you might find you're using incompatible jars.

Comment: Alex: Thanks for your quick response. I have updated post with my dependencies. Please have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found [this](https://community.jboss.org/message/565026) previous discussion. Perhaps you should try some of these suggestions. There is also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097567/jboss-and-different-versions-of-hibernate) previous stack overflow discussion.

It seems to be caused by differences between the version of Hibernate in your dependencies and the one bundled with your JBoss app server.

Comment: Awesome Alex, You made my day :)
I was looking for same solution.

Answer (score 3):

For reference I am posting here what was the issue and what I did:

**ISSUE**

There was a conflict with hibernate jars I have added in my maven dependencies and that of jboss-as/commons/lib/

**SOLUTION:**

Added following properties to use only maven dependencies:

`<property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl">false</property>

<property name="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners">false</property>`